# What does the WinDbg command prompt indicate?

Tags: command-line, prompt, windbg

I'm using [WinDbg](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/) and am wondering what the WinDbg command prompt indicates. In my case, the command prompt reads

> 2: kd>

I assume the kd means I'm debugging in kernel-mode (as opposed to user-mode, see [Getting Started with Windows Debugging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/getting-started-with-windows-debugging)). Is that correct? What would the prompt look like if I were debugging in user-mode?

Also, the `2:` seems to indicate the current processor, since when I change the current processor to 0 using the command `~0s`, the prompt also changes:

> 0: kd>

Is there an article or summary that explains the different formats the WinDbg command prompt can appear in and what the meaning is of the values shown in those formats?

Answer (score 0):

I found the official documentation [Using Debugger Commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-debugger-commands) by Microsoft. It contains a section explaining the Debugger Command Window Prompt. It explains:

- `2: kd>` indicates kernel-mode debugging (`kd`) with the current processor being number 2.
- Examples of the prompt during user-mode debugging are `2:005>` and `3:2:005>`, where 005 is the current thread number, 2 is the current process number and the leading 3 is the current system number which is only shown in situations where the debugger is attached to more than one computer system.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.